# Resize a texture using the full SpriteBatch.Draw in XNA

Tags: xna, rendering

I'm using the full Spritebatch.Draw function to draw my explosion sprite since I also need rotation. I am using the Scale value to resize my texture, but I can't get it to be accurate.

I want to be able to set the textures Size to a specific pixel size, width/height are exactly the same. Say the texture is 128x128, and I want to resize it to be 23x23.

Heres my current code:

```
  Vector2 Scale = new Vector2((float)sprite.Area.Width / (float)sprite.Texture.Width, (float)sprite.Area.Height / (float)sprite.Texture.Height);
            spriteBatch.Draw(sprite.Texture, sprite.Position, null, sprite.Color * sprite.Alpha, (float)Math.Atan2(sprite.Angle.Y, sprite.Angle.X), new Vector2(sprite.Area.Width / 2, sprite.Area.Height / 2), Scale, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
```

I have the Area set to be the size I want it at, however the Draw function seems to not be drawing it to the exact size.

Comment: I don't understand yet. What do you want and how does the output differ from that? Since we're talking about sprites here, a screenshot would be really useful.

Answer (score 2):

Since it looks like you are using the `Scale` parameter, you will need to calculate the correct scale value based on the original and target size. Since the `Scale` parameter is a float, and not a pixel size, you'll need to calculate the percentage your target is of your source.

> If your resource is 128x128, and you draw at scale `1.0f`, your output
>   will be 128x128.
>
> If your resource is 128x128, and you draw at scale `0.5f`, your output
>   will be 64x64.
>
> If your resource is 128x128, and you draw at scale `0.179f`, your
>   output will be 23x23 (rounding may make this slightly different,
>   adjust scale accordingly.

The formula for uniform scaling as you are asking, would be `Scale = TargetSize/SourceSize`.

For additional information, and alternate approaches (i.e. using a destination rectangle instead of a scaling factor) see [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb194913.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

In the *destination* variable of Draw() use a new Rectangle() so that you can specify the not just the position of the draw but the size also.

Rectangles properties

```
Height  Specifies the height of the rectangle.
Width   Specifies the width of the rectangle.
X       Specifies the x-coordinate of the rectangle.
Y       Specifies the y-coordinate of the rectangle.
```

Use X,Y for the location and Height,Width for the size.